# HTML Hovered Dropdown Menu Inside A Hovered Dropdown

Tags: html, css

Please don't be rude, im new on here and dont know much about this site, if you do answer my issue, it would help if you leave a "explanation" of what you changed, added, etc. and what it would do

I want to have a menu that has a dropdown, but inside the dropdown will be another dropdown menu [Image of what I'm talking about, (red being the area of the dropdown menu that's inside the other dropdown menu)]
[image: 1]

codes given below first is style.css, second is index.html

```css
body
{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #FFB6C1;
}

ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #FFC0CB;
}

label.logo
{
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

li
{
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn
{
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn
{
    background: #ffaebd;
}

li.dropdown
{
    display: inline-block;
}

li.dropdown a, .dropbtn
{
    color: white;
}


.dropdown-content
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: #201e2a;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
}

.dropdown-content a
{
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
.dropdown a:hover
{
    background: #ffaebd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content
{
    display: block;
}

/* next */

body
{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #FFB6C1;
}
/* FFA07A */
ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #FFC0CB;
}

label.logo
{
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

li
{
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
            <title>Test</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <label class="logo">Test Page</label>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown Menu</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="x/y/z.html">Link One</a>
                <a href="z/y/x.html">Link Two</a>
                <a href="#">Sub Dropdown</a>
                 <!-- (set to this instead of a dropdown just for showcase/ss reasons) -->
            </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want both dropdown on hover right?

Comment: Please do not add a link to your code; see [mcve]. Links can rot, people might not be able to access the website, there might be licensing issues etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by putting your exact code of dropdown inside your sub dropdown

```
<li class="dropdown"> 
       <a id="drpbtn" class="dropbtn">Dropdown Menu</a>
        <div aria-label="drpbtn" class="dropdown-content">
           <a href="x/y/z.html">Link One</a>
           <a href="z/y/x.html">Link Two</a>
            <a href="#" id="drpbtn2">Sub dropdown btn</a>
            <div aria-label="drpbtn2" class="sub-dropdown-content">
            <a href="x/y/z.html">Link One</a>
            <a href="z/y/x.html">Link Two</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        </li>
```

Comment: [Results](https://i.imgur.com/owgIa2e.png) it doesnt hide the options in the subdropdown, as well as there now being "btn" added the the text

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of how you can do this and I try to keep it as simple as possible to understand how it works :

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
}

.menu {
  display: block;
}

li {
  padding: 16px;
}

li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    Hover me !
    <ul>
      <li>Menu Item</li>
      <li>
        Menu Item
        <ul>
          <li>Menu Item</li>
          <li>
            Menu Item
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-grass-1byw0b